# Accurate way to estimate output video size from an AVAssetExportSession

Tags: ios, video, export, avfoundation, avassetexportsession

I'm building a video trimmer and exporter and would like to display the estimated output file size for a video based on the trimmed time range and export preset values. The source video I'm testing with is ~31MB.

The `AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality` and `AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality` preset estimates a quite accurate. They report an estimated output size of 1.6MB and 7.8MB respectively, and the actual exported videos are basically that size.

However, all other valid export preset qualities are wildly inaccurate. For example, the `AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality` exports at the original file size of 31MB, but is estimated to export at 257MB. Not even close.

Anyone have an idea of why these values are so far off? Here's my sample export code as well as the estimated and actual file sizes.

```
let presets = [
    AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality,
    AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality,
    AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality,
    AVAssetExportPreset640x480,
    AVAssetExportPreset960x540,
    AVAssetExportPreset1280x720,
    AVAssetExportPreset1920x1080
]

let formatter = ByteCountFormatter()
formatter.allowedUnits = [.useMB, .useKB]

let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "big_buck_bunny", withExtension: "mp4")!
let asset = AVURLAsset(url: url)

for preset in presets {
    let session = AVAssetExportSession(asset: asset, presetName: preset)!

    let output = (NSTemporaryDirectory() as NSString).appendingPathComponent(preset + ".mp4")
    session.timeRange = CMTimeRange(start: .zero, end: asset.duration)
    session.outputURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: output)
    session.outputFileType = .mp4
    session.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true

    print("Estimated size for \(preset): \(formatter.string(fromByteCount: Int64(session.estimatedOutputFileLength)))")

    session.exportAsynchronously {
        print(session.outputURL)
    }
}
```

Reported estimated output sizes:

```
Estimated size for AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality: 1.6 MB
Estimated size for AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality: 7.8 MB
Estimated size for AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality: 257.6 MB
Estimated size for AVAssetExportPreset640x480: 37 MB
Estimated size for AVAssetExportPreset960x540: 54.9 MB
Estimated size for AVAssetExportPreset1280x720: 109.7 MB
Estimated size for AVAssetExportPreset1920x1080: 155.6 MB
```

Actual output sizes:

```
Actual size for AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality: 1.6 MB
Actual size for AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality: 7.8 MB
Actual size for AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality: 30.7 MB
Actual size for AVAssetExportPreset640x480: 27 MB
Actual size for AVAssetExportPreset960x540: 51.5 MB
Actual size for AVAssetExportPreset1280x720: 100.8 MB
Actual size for AVAssetExportPreset1920x1080: 30.7 MB
```

Also, it's weird that the 960x540 and 1280x720 export at a size greater than the original, which has a resolution of 1920x1080.

Comment: One thing I've learned recently is that nobody seems to have much knowledge in iOS video and image compression :(

Answer (score 0):

The actual exported file size depends on the compression rate of the original video. I guess `estimatedOutputFileLength` returns the worst-case estimation so it is larger than actual size.